# Android: Can't get Imei from a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, imei

I have a service that stars a new thread. My task is to retrieve the IMEI from this thread. I ve tried something like this:

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String imei;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TelephonyManager mg=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    imei = mg.getDeviceId();


    Intent intent = new Intent();
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));

}

public String getIMEI(){
    Log.d("THIS IS THE IMEI", imei);
    return imei;
}
```

This is my Service Class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
Connection con = new Connection();
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){

    Thread t = new Thread(con);
    t.start();
}
```

And this is my Runnable class:

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {
MainActivity app = new MainActivity();

@Override
public void run() {
   String imei = app.getIMEI();
}
```

But when my code reach `String imei = app.getIMEI()` my application crashes and throws and Exception.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asder.vediamo/com.asder.vediamo.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10057 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

In my android manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyService"/>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What's wrong if you get `IMEI` directly in your `Runnable` class?

Comment: Which API level currently using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MainActivity app = new MainActivity();
```

don't use the `new` operator on a class that extends `Activity`. In your case you are initializing `imei`, but your Activity is not going through is lifecycle, since you used `new` to instantiate it. Service has the possibility to access the `TelephonyManager`, if this is available. If you need to use the imei in your `Thread`, you can provide it in its constructor. E.g.

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {

    final String imei;
    public Connection(String i) {
      imei = i;
    }
```

in your `Service`'s `onCreate` you can retrieve the `imei` (you need the service to go through its lifecycle as well) and instantiate the `Runnable` , providing the imei to the constructor

Comment: I have tried to retrieve the IMEI from my Service.. but it throws the same exception.. So i think it is not possible to retrieve it inside the service.`@Override
    public void onCreate(){
        TelephonyManager mg=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        String imei = mg.getDeviceId();

        Log.d("TESTTTT",imei);`

Comment: are you targeting marshmallow ? on which device are you getting the exception ?

Comment: I m getting the exception inside an emulator android 6.0 and in my phone andorid 5.1.1

Comment: Are you sure you get the exactly same exception on android 5.1.1  ?

Comment: Ok I solved.. I had a problem in my phone.. Now works perfectly

Comment: what problem did you have?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating an Activity by yourself, you should never do this:

```
MainActivity app = new MainActivity();
```

If you need a context use the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class, and get context from it. Activities are always created the OS via `startActivity` command.

Then try to use that context to obtain the TelephonyManager and the IMEI...

Comment: Do you have a class that extends Application?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer and must test the our App on many devices.
I found the same problem on my new Cagabi One: The IMEI request generate a SecurityException when read data from my Service.
My App work correctly on some other devices included another Cagabi One, but not in the new one.
So, I have solved by **reading and saved the IMEI number at startup of the Application (in the main thread)** and so read the value saved from my Service.
The procedure work fine now! ;-)
My suggestion is to read always all Hardware values from main Thread for to exclude conflicts and security exception.
Roberto.